# Tensorboard eval.py IOU for object detection

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, tensorboard

I used the ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco from detection model zoo in tensorflow object detection. I am currently training the model by running

```
python legacy/train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=trainingmobile/ --pipeline_config_path=trainingmobile/pipeline.config
```

I want to run an evaluation job by running eval.py to get other metrics like IOU and PR Curve but I don't know how to do that. I am able to run the command

```
python legacy/eval.py \
--logtostderr \
--checkpoint_dir= path/to/checkpoint \
--eval_dir= path/to/eval \
--pipeline_config_path= path/to/config
```

then I ran the command

```
tensorboard --logdir=path/to/eval
```

The tensorboard shows only the test image output. How can i get other metrics like IOU and PR Curve?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, I'd highly recommend you to use the newer `model_main.py` script for training and evaluation combined. You can use it as shown below:

```
python object_detection/model_main.py \
   --pipeline_config_path=path/to/config \
   --model_dir=path/to/train_dir \
   --num_train_steps=NUM_TRAIN_STEPS \
   --num_eval_steps=NUM_EVAL_STEPS \
   --alsologtostderr
```

It combines training and evaluation and you can enter tensorboard with

```
tensorboard -logdir=path/to/train_dir
```

Tensorboard will not only disply the training process, it will also show your progress over your validation set. They use the COCO metric as default metric!

To your original problem: Maybe you should change the eval settings in your config file to larger numbers:

```
eval_config: {
  num_examples: 8000
  # Note: The below line limits the evaluation process to 10 evaluations.
  # Remove the below line to evaluate indefinitely.
  max_evals: 10}
```

If you'll use the `model_main.py` script, the number of evaluation will be set by the flags.

Good to know: The info output of tnesorflow is disabled in the newer `model_main.py` script. You can enable it by adding

```
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)
```

after the import section.

Comment: Hi if num_eval_steps = 10, does that mean that every 10 steps, the model will evaluate be evaluated against the test data to determine IOU or Precision etc? Sorry Im new to this thanks

Comment: Don't worry! No, num_eval_steps = 10 means, that for each evaluation cycle, it will calculate 10 steps. So for example, if your batch size is 1, it will evaluate 10 (random) images in your validation set and calculate the mAP and Recall based on these results. So if you have something like 1000 images in your validation set, you should set num_eval_steps to a (much) smaller number than 1000, because you don't want to evaluate all images in your validation set for every cycle (maybe something around 50~100 would be fine).

Comment: @Thommy257, is this `--num_train_steps=NUM_TRAIN_STEPS` is the same thing as `num_steps`  in config file. I did not set these three parameters 
   `--num_train_steps=NUM_TRAIN_STEPS` 
   `--num_eval_steps=NUM_EVAL_STEPS` 
   `--alsologtostderr`. With tensorboard I can see training loss and precision recall separate line curves and output images along with ground truths. When I click on `pr_curve` tab on tensorboard it does not show anything, what did I miss ? I was hoping to see something like this https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/tree/master/tensorboard/plugins/pr_curve